# Запись пути в файл в терминале Linux

Tags: linux

В директории /home/box/root находится файл. Необходимо записать в этот файл полный путь, по которому он располагается.
помогите пожалуйста. Нигде не могу найти хоть что-то похожее!!!

Comment: Разбейте задачу на два этапа: 1. как получить полный путь файла в виде строки 2. как записать строку в файл.

Answer (score 3):

`find`

```
# создаем тестовый файл
touch /home/box/root/name-of-file
# Ищем этот файл в каталоге и записываем что нашли
find /home/box/ -type f -name name-of-file > /home/box/root/name-of-file
# Проверяем
cat /hom/box/root/name-of-file
/hom/box/root/name-of-file
```

В одну строчку немного посложней

```
find /hom/box/root/ -type f -name name-of-file -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c "echo {} > {}"
```

`find` и `xargs` части пакета [findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)